# Restore Activities Overview button on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome

After installing ARC Menu on Ubuntu 18.04, the Activities button disappeared from the system tray. How can I get the workspace manager back on my desktop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Gnome tweaks app or extension app , If not installed then

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Go to extensions tab

Simply turn off the arc menu first , You will see that activities  overview is back then click on settings button and change the position to wherever  you prefer then turn it on

As I can see in comments you are not able to install and enable dash to dock , Here are steps to install it

Installation from source
The extension can be installed directly from source, either for the convenience of using git or to test the latest development version. Clone the desired branch with git

```
 git clone https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock.git
```

or download the branch from github. The master branch usually target the latest GNOME Shell version. There are gnome-3.x branch with the latest code for older versions. In case you are running a development version ( that is an even version), although the extension is not guaranteed to work, you should look for a development branch and manually add your version in the metadata.json. Sometimes the previous stable version works with minor bugs also in the development GNOME Shell.

A simple Makefile is included. Run

```
make
make install
```

to install the extension in your home directory. A Shell reload is required Alt+F2 r Enter and the extension has to be enabled with gnome-tweak-tool or with dconf.

As an alternative the zip archive can be generated with

```
make
make zip-file
```

Then follow the instructions above to install the zip-archive.

This will help in installing the extension.

Then open gnome extensions app or gnome tweaks app or just run

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
gnome-tweaks
```

Go to extensions > dash to dock > ON

Then turn of the Ubuntu dock extension.

Then just configure it by right clicking on the application launcher button > Dash to dock settings .

You can do any configurations you want and like.

After just messing it with for like 5mins only you would be a professional dash to dock configurer .

Then you can do the things with arc menu as you like

Comment: The only position options are Main Panel, left, center, or right; dash to panel; and dash to dock. Moving the arc button from the left to the center or right of the panel doesn't cause the Activities button to reappear on the left. I am told that the other extensions are not enabled. I'm not clear about what dash to dock is, but I downloaded it to my Downloads directory, and don't know how to get it running from there. Since I don't know if that extension will change other things I'm presently happy with, and the top bar repositioning didn't do anything, I'm stuck with Activities in the menu.

Comment: Dash to dock is an extremely configurable dock,You can download and install it and replace it with the Ubuntu Dock , BTW Ubuntu dock is the modifies version of dash to dock , So it would be great if you download it and then modify it to your needs . Also don't install it from the GitHub file instead download it from the chrome shell extension or gnome shell extension from firefox , If you say I can add some details about that in my answer , But it would be helpful to me If you do it yourself by watching tutorials on YouTube about how to download and configure dash to dock to look like ubuntu

Comment: Also plz upvote and accept this answer to give me some reputation , Also I am happy to help if you're unable to download and configure dash to dock

Comment: In a terminal, I reinstalled gnome-shell-extensions and dconf-editor. In dconf-editor, I navigated to dash to dock, where I turned on Ubuntu dock. In Arc menu settings, when I select to display it on Dash to Dock, I still get "Dash to Dock extension not running! Enable Dash to Dock for this feature to work."

Comment: What are you even saying ?

Comment: I told you to install dash to dock !! Not this thing

Comment: Go to gnome extensions web page and there enable the extension !!! What is it to do with dconf ??? Don't end up resetting your entire desktop !! Dconf is dangerous

Comment: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/307/dash-to-dock/. From here you can turn on the extension instead of download it.

Comment: If it says that ```To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension and native host messaging application.
Click here to install browser extension. See wiki page for native host connector installation instructions.``` then click on click here link in the message and download the extension, To turn it on using your browser

Comment: I updated my answer , If you want more details

Comment: I had thought you suggested it would be helpful to learn how to do it on YouTube. That's where a search for how to download and configure dash to dock led me to instructions on using dconf. In Firefox's extension for Gnome, I installed Dash to Dock and, after a few tries, got the arc menu on the dock, with Activities still on the top bar. Thank you for your patience.